# Deploying Quasar (VueJS) with vue-router in Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vue-router, firebase-hosting, quasar-framework

[image]

I'm having this view on my webpage. It says, it was successfully deployed but it's not showing my SPA.

**config**:

```
 "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/spa-mat",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

Im using default **router.js** setup

```
 {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/default'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/index') }
    ]
  }
```

**Steps taken**:

```
(firebase already installed an im already logged in)
1. quasar build - to build quasar app for prod
2. firebase init
           - `dist/spa-mat` as directory 
3. firebase deploy
```

Any Quasar dev who has an idea how to deploy in Firebase hosting? I think I did everything right but my SPA is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the official docs for [Deployment of SPA in Quasar](https://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-deploying-spa.html). There's a guide there how to deploy in Heroko, Now, etc.

If you're doing it right, give it several minutes to an hour.

Comment: As much as I hate to admit it, I did give it sometime. Now it's live. hahaha, thanks